# Flatten list with EF SelectMany

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linqpad

I want to go ahead and get all or at least some of the columns from my Projects table which has a one to many relationship with my TimeTrackings table.

When I create the query, only all the child (TimeTracking entity) fields come out and just the ID of the parent (Project table).

How can I achieve an effective join using the SelectMany to flatten a list getting all the columns or at least specifying specific columns from each of the two entities.

Below, is the EF query I'm using:

```
Customers.SelectMany(p => p.Projects).Where (p => p.Quote != null).SelectMany (t => t.TimeTrackings).Where (t => t.Notes != null)
```

Below is the generated SQL query via LINQPad. **Notice how only the ProjectID and not the rest of the associated columns for that entity come out.**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent2].[TimeTrackingID] AS [TimeTrackingID], 
    [Extent2].[ProjectID] AS [ProjectID], 
    [Extent2].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    [Extent2].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
    [Extent2].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
    [Extent2].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate]
    FROM  [dbo].[Projects] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TimeTrackings] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProjectID] = [Extent2].[ProjectID]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Quote] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Notes] IS NOT NULL)
```

Below, is the output of the query:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form the Linq as following

```
from c in Customers
from p in c.Projects
from t in p.TimeTrackings
where p.Quotes != null
where t.Notes != null
select new { Project = p, TimeTrack = t }
```

Also, can change the select statement to project individual properties

```
select new { ProjectId = p.Id, TimeTrackId = t.Id, Anything = p.Anything }
```

Comment: This would seem like a more logical resolution using the QUERY syntax where INNER JOINS are produced to get the desired columns.

Answer (score 1):

May be what you are looking for is the `Select` method to do a projection of columns:

```
Customers.SelectMany(p => p.Projects)
         .Where (p => p.Quote != null)
         .SelectMany (t => t.TimeTrackings)
         .Where (t => t.Notes != null)
         .Select(x => new { x.ProjectID, x.Project.Name, x.Project.CustomerId });
```

Comment: This solution would also work, but I figured why am I using the METHOD syntax to create joins instead of the above QUERY syntax. Both will work, but it seems more natural to use the QUERY syntax to do the joins as opposed to the METHOD syntax. If that's the case, why do I need to use the SelectMany operation? The QUERY syntax above accomplishes the INNER JOIN more so than the SelectMany. the SelectMany doesn't even include any properties of the Customer entity. If that's the case, in what particular situation would I need to use the SelectMany method?